# nodejs written file is empty

Tags: node.js, streamwriter

i have a small problem, when i try to copy one file from my tmp dir to my ftp dir the writen file is empty. I have no error, i don't understand what i'm doing wrong

```
var ftpPath = "/var/www/ftp/",
    zipPath = "/var/www/tmp/",
    file = "test";
fs.createReadStream(zipPath + file).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(ftpPath + file));
```

My test file contain loremipsum sample.

If you have any solution, i take it, this is the only line that bug in my app :(

Comment: Where do you see any documentation that `fs.createWriteStream()` accepts a second argument that is a stream?  I don't see that here: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options.  It seems more like you need to pipe one stream into the other.

Comment: Ooops this is a mistake, i take the wrong line of my code. This line was a risky test. I got empty file with pipe too :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that the file **/var/www/tmp/test** exists, is a file, and has the right permissions for the user you start the script with.

Second, make sure that **/var/www/ftp/** has writing permissions.

Then the following code should work :

```
var readerStream = fs.createReadStream('/var/www/tmp/test');
var writerStream = fs.createWriteStream('/var/www/ftp/test');
readerStream.pipe(writerStream);
```

**Edit :**

try debugging using this snippet :

```
var data;
var readerStream = fs.createReadStream('/var/www/tmp/test');
readerStream.on('data', function(data) {
  data += data;
});

readerStream.on('end', function() {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Currently i made my tests with the root account. I have tried your solution but the file test (chmod 777) still empty, the ftp directory is chmod 755.

Comment: Double check that /var/www/tmp/test contains data, in case you may have emptied the file while testing stuff?

Comment: Also, try deleting the file in /var/www/ftp and see if your code creates it.

Comment: as I said in my request, the test file contains a lorem ipsum, the file as been created when i delete it.

Comment: Could your program be exiting before the command is executed? try adding setTimeout(function(){console.log('waiting')},1000) to give it time to write.

Comment: .on('data') seem doesn't work, i have put console.log('data event'); into but nothing appear :o

Comment: With your answer i discover the pipe end event, with it i have solved my problem, so i accept your answer for this reason.